# $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-5}} \operatorname d\!x$ by substitution?

Tags: calculus

I need to evaluate the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-5}} dx$$

The integral should be solved by substitution. I tried substituting $u=x^2-5$, but did not come with an answer.The correct answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt 5}{x}\right)$.

Comment: You have a square root of a quadratic and you know your solution has an inverse trig function.  Have you considered a trig substitution?

Comment: Use $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sin(u)}=\sqrt{5}\csc(u)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Use the change of variable
$$x=\sqrt 5\cosh u$$

Comment: Succinct and spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let's rearrange the equation as:
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x^2}}}dx
$$
This is done by pulling the $x^2$ out of the square root.

So using the substitution as provided we get 
$$
du = \frac{-\sqrt{5}}{x^2}dx
$$
Which you should see helps you solve the integral as required. In the standard form of the trigonometric integral.

Comment: how did you get du=-(5)^.5/x^2dx? what was u equal to?

Comment: I thought the substitution in the question was $u=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{x}$. After reading the OP that wasn't the sub he was using, but the one in this comment was the one I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Like I put in my comment, the square root of a quadratic often suggests a trig substitution, which takes one of 3 forms:

$$1-\sin^2x=\cos^2x$$
$$\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$$
$$\sec^2x-1=\tan^2x$$

In this case, you have something squared minus a constant, so the third form is what we want.  The substitution $x=\sqrt5\sec t$ will reduce the square root to $\sqrt{5\tan^2t}$.  If you perform the substitution correctly, you should end up integrating a constant.